# Popup hide after `Click`

Tags: angular, bootstrap-modal, ngx-bootstrap

[Popup will close while click on close-icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jOZy.png)

PopUps hide only after `click` on `Close` or `Cancel` Icon not by click anywhere on the screen or pressing the `ESC` Button.

```html
<div bsModal #bsModalRef="bs-modal" [config]="{backdrop: false,keyboard: false}" aria-hidden="true" aria-label="Close" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()">
  <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

Comment: Format your code properly

Comment: @SangamBelose please send to me a proper formation of that code.. I have used cancel and close icons to close that pop-up

Comment: What do you mean send me the proper formation.? Initially your code was not formatted properly. Stack overflow has its guidelines to post your question.Please follow https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: <span class="close-icon" (click)="bsModalRef.hide()" ><i class="fa fa-times"></i></span> i used this code for popup close.But i need to close my pop-up window only click on that close icon.Not for anywhere on the screen.Please send me that proper code for thatpurpose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add data-backdrop and data-keyboard properties for the button/link that is calling the modal popup. Sample Code below:

```
<button title="Save & Submit" type="button" class="btn btn-default ok-button" data-toggle="modal" data-backdrop="static" data-keyboard="false" data-target="#divSaveNewAssetStructure">Save & Submit</button>
```

Comment: without using modal-popups there is any other solution will be there for that pop-up close??